# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString isDescendantOfView:]:

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I have received the crash in the app

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString isDescendantOfView:]:

Is anybody face similar to this issue.

Comment: Can you give some more details or crash report about exception you received? Or explain what you are doing in your code?

Comment: As vague as your information I guess that you're using somewhere a literal string instead of a variable containing an `UIView` instance

Comment: The error stated that you are calling a UIView method isDescendantOfView from an NSCFString class.  Check the calling object.

Comment: Add a breakpoint for all exception, you will know where it is crashing.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are sending the message `isDescendantOfView:` to an instance of an `NSString` class. NSString classes does not respond to such selectors.

`isDescendantOfView:` is a method that belongs to `UIView` [classes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/isDescendantOfView:).

The compiler normally prevents you from doing such things but it may be related to the fact that you handle `id` types (that means 'An object of an unknown type'). In such cases, the compiler can't help you since the real type is only known at runtime. Make sure you call the method on the right object.